Fixing boost::optional undefined type error
I was trying to create a bidirectional tree-like structure, so Ive ended up with the following struct`s:
    template<typename T>
    struct Node
    {
        T value;
        std::vector<Node<T>> kids;
        boost::optional<Node<T>> parent { boost::none };
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Tree
    {
        std::vector<Node<T>> heads;
    };


But when I tried to use such Tree/Node as, for instance, value in unordered_map, I got compilation error (MSVC 17.0, C++ 14):
...\boost\include\boost/optional/detail/optional_aligned_storage.hpp(31): error C2027: use of undefined type "Node<std::shared_ptr<Action>>"

After some googling and asking Chat-GPT, it was suggested to replace
boost::optional<Node<T>> parent { boost::none };


with
boost::optional<std::reference_wrapper<Node<T>>> parent { boost::none };

That worked.
However, I honestly have no idea why exactly.
Can anyone explaing that?
Minimal reproducible example on godbolt: click;

boost::optional requires a complete type, and at that point Node is not complete.  std::reference_wrapper make it a pointer-like entity that does not require a complete type.

Node<T>* parent = nullptr; might be an alternative.

Oftentimes, you just use pointers for this. Usually, you can also use the nullptr instead of the optional thing (also, consider std::optional instead of boost -- I use boost a lot, but only with stuff that C++ doesn't already have). Also, keep in mind that using references to other nodes, instead of the actual nodes, means that you have to take care of cleanups -- I don't know how your structure is supposed to work, so maybe std::unique_ptr would be useful here, as that will also clean up the parent, just like an embedded node would.

You don't need boost::optional here, use a raw pointer.


Can anyone explaing that?

boost::optional requires a complete type. Node is not yet complete when you attempt to define parent using it (it will be complete after ; at the end of the struct definition).
The reason boost::optional<T> requires a complete type is that it holds T inside itself. In your case this would require Node to hold a Node inside itself which is impossible.
You can see some more info about complete and incomplete types here: When does an Incomplete Type error occur in C++
Using std::reference_wrapper solves the problem because it makes std::reference_wrapper<Node<T>> a pointer-like objects. Such objects do not require the pointee to the a complete type (roughly speaking it's because all pointers are similar, no matter what they point to).
Intead of boost::optional and std::reference_wrapper you can simply use a raw pointer and have:
Node<T> * parent { nullptr };

You can use nullptr as an equivalent to an empty boost::optional.

@Evg nicely put. I added it to the answer.

Didn`t know boost::optional requires a complete type. Thanks!
